# SQL "вычитание" из count по условию

Tags: sql, oracle, count

БД системы типа Service Desk (Oracle 10g), делаю выборку из БД для отчета из основной таблицы с задачами, нужно сделать выборку  по типу задачи с количеством открытых, закрытых и т.д.  причем внутри одного из типов задач, нужно исключить (вычесть или чтобы они не считались) из выборки задачи относящиеся к определенному ПО (`TBL_TASK.USSYSTEMS`). 
Загвоздка как раз получается в этом вычитании, можно конечно сделать импорт в excel и подправить руками, но хочется разобраться возможно ли в SLQ сделать подобное?
запрос типа:

```
SELECT  
TBL_TASK.TYPE,
count (TBL_TASK.ID),
count(case whenN TBL_TASK.STATE = 'resolved' or TBL_TASK.STATE = 'closed' then 1 else null),
.....
GROUP BY TBL_TASK.TYPE
```

Comment: А выборки к ПО должны быть проигнорированны только в одном типе задач или во всех типах?

Comment: Вы бы переписали вопрос по человечески. Перечитал его 5 раз, так и не понял до конца, что надо сделать.

Comment: Ну вот вы же считаете по какомй то state, так же условиями можно учитывать и другие поля, тот же ussystems например. А средствами SQL можно сделать вообще все, что угодно, главное правильно сформулировать что же нужно сделать

Comment: Да,  ПО должно быть проигнорировано только  в одном типе задач.  Ниже Zufir сдал правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить `COUNT` на `SUM(CASE WHEN <условие которое должно добавляться> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: почему `...ELSE -1 END`, а не ноль?

Comment: А, действительно. Не уменьшать, а не учитывать. Проглядел.